# Calculation of Laurent series and decomposition in partial fractions

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

So I was asked to find the Laurent series of the expression around $z=2$:
$$f(z)= \frac{z+3}{(z-2)^3}$$

I am aware that this can be decomposed as $$5\, \left( z-2 \right) ^{-3}+ \left( z-2 \right) ^{-2}$$
Is this the entire Laurent series of $f(z)$ around $z=2$. I am asking because in order to derive this I haven't even used the fact that expansion is being carried out about $2$. If so why?

Comment: What you're aware of is already an expression s Laurent series of terms of the form $\;(z-2)^n\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z\;$ , which is a Laurent series about $\;z=2\;$ ...

Comment: Laurent series of a function about a single fixed point is unique.

Comment: @onurcanbektas but in order to convert into partial fractions I have not even used the fact the expansion is around $z=2$. So how would the expansion look like if it was about $z=1$?

Comment: You would have to do some algebraic tricks, for example to write $$z-2=(z-1)-1\implies\frac1{z-2}=\frac1{-1+(z-1)}$$ and then develop...

Comment: @daljit97 Well the denominator of the function is already $z-2$, so you use it actually, it is saying something like $z+0 = 0$, so you did not notice. If you want to look at the laurent series of $f$ about $1$, there is a formula to calculate the coef. of $(z-1)^k$ for all $k$; you can find it on wikipedia probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

".. about $z=2$" means you have to derive an expression of terms $(z-2)$. In this particular case, the fraction decomposition leads to

$$f(x) = \frac{z+3}{(z-2)^3} = \frac{1}{(z-2)^2} + \frac{5}{(z-2)^2}$$

which is already an expanded expression involving $(z-2)$ terms (of the form $(z-2)^n, n \in \mathbb Z$) , thus a Laurent expansion of the function $f(z)$. But, each Laurent expansion for a function is unique (check the adequate theorem in your notes). Thus this is the desired result.

Now, regarding to your comment for an expansion about $z=1$, this is a different case and you should work on your initial $f$ to create $(z-1)^n, n \in \mathbb Z$ terms.